# IE not blocking javascript

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

It seems that IE8 defers javascript, but also doesn't block. I've setup a test environment to prove this. Here's the html page(replace 192.168.1.xxx with your server):

```
<html>
<head>
 <title>IE Pains</title>
 <script type='text/javascript' src='http://192.168.1.xxx/ietest/js.js'></script>
 <script type='text/javascript'>
  scream('hello world');
 </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

And the js File:

```
function scream( str ) {
 alert( str );
}
```

Am I seeing this wrong, or does IE not recognize the scream function because it hasn't finished loading js.js?

**EDIT**: I created the pages on my server: http://www.codenothing.com/ietest/, which loads fine in IE8, but bringing it down to local machine, and going through local network seems to be failing. I have confirmed this on 2 different wireless networks going through the 192.168 protocol.

Comment: Are you sure the path to that `js.js` is correct?

Comment: It shouldn't be the case. Can you post the contents of your external js?

Comment: @Chetan - He did, in the question :)

Comment: @Nick: Aw crap. I blame it on my short attention span.

Comment: Is the calling page being executed via a `file://` URI? or is it also an http page?  That can make a difference.

Comment: It's also being called from http://192.168.1.xxx/ietest/

Answer (score 2):

Scripts are blocking in all browsers, including IE8, unless the `async` or `defer` attributes are present.  Vast amounts of scripts rely on the predictability of script elements blocking parsing, including libraries and frameworks (for instance, how could you declare `$(document).ready()` if the browser didn't wait for the jQuery script to complete?)

Check the following:

- There are no syntax errors or typos in the JS file.
- The path to the JS file is correct.
- The function is declared in the global scope.

You could even try the jQuery library itself:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    alert("test");
});
</script>
```

Comment: Also, everything you said is right, that's why I am so confused as to why it's across only the local network.